# Can't git pull when I modify README in github

Tags: git, github

I modified my README.md file in github.

When I try `git pull origin master` it shows that error:

```
error: unable to unlink old 'README.md' (Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means the the existing README.md on your disk is open in a program, so git can't delete it.

Comment: So, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: I deleted the file in my local copy and it shows the same error.

Comment: @Sadiel so the problem was not an open file, but you had wrong permissions on your repository. Surely you cloned your repository using `sudo`. I'd suggest you to re-clone it as a normal user.